# jquery ajax get return value

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

i want to get the 'printed value' of html pages.

i tried below query, but showGetResult() just return 'null value'

but my apache server logs printed i accessed index.php when i try this code.

(index.php just print helloworld)

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"><\script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showGetResult( name )
{
     var result = null;
     jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/index.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'text/html',
        success:function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
            result = data;
        } 
     });
     return result;
}

document.write(showGetResult('test'));
</script>
```

Comment: add async: false,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think what you want to do is this.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"><\script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showGetResult( name )
{
     jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/index.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'text/html',
        success:function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
            document.write(data);
        } 
     });
}

showGetResult('test');
</script>
```

Comment: Is there a way to assign it to a variable? Or at least keep the window updating?

Comment: @YJiqdAdwTifMxGR old question I know, but the only answer I've seen that actually returns a value and assigns it to a variable is here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71544695/12956240

Answer (score 5):

This is the way AJAX works (asynchronously, like the name suggests). The `showGetResult` function returns before the AJAX call completes. `showGetResult` will therefore simply return `null` since that's what you've assigned to `result`.

Move any code that depends on the result of the AJAX call inside the `success` callback. Alternatively, you could make the call synchronous, but that's not usually what you want.

Answer (score 0):

AJAX requests are aynchronous by default; you can't return their result in a function, you need to use callbacks. The easiest way to achieve what you want is to put your code that handles your data in your `success` handler:

```
    success:function(data)
    {
        alert(data);
        result = data;
        document.write(showGetResult('test'));
    }
```

Also, don't use `document.write`.

Answer (score 0):

You have the wrong `dataType` per the documentation for [jQuery.ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/):

> "html": Returns HTML as plain text; included script tags are evaluated when inserted in the DOM.

So you want to use `html`:

```
...
dataType: 'html',
...
```

---

In addition, as others have said, the ajax request is asynchronous. So you need to restructure your code. For example:

```
function showGetResult( name )
{
 var result = null;
 jQuery.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost/index.php',
    type: 'get',
    dataType: 'html',
    success:function(data)
    {
        alert(data);
        result = data;
        document.write(result);
    } 
 });
}

showGetResult('test');
```

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a fundamental point here. The `success` method is not run when you call showGetResult. It is run [asynchronously](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asynchrony).

At the point that you put `return result;` it is still null (because `success` has not yet been invoked).

What you need to do is have document.write execute after success is invoked. Either like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"><\script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showGetResult( name )
{
     var result = null;
     jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/index.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'text/html',
        success:function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
            document.write(data);
        } 
     });
     return result;
}

//document.write(showGetResult('test'));
showGetResult('test');
</script>
```

Or with a callback:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"><\script>
<script type="text/javascript">
function showGetResult( name )
{
     var result = null;
     jQuery.ajax({
        url: 'http://localhost/index.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'text/html',
        success:function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
            writeToDocument(data);
        } 
     });
}

function writeToDocument(data) {
   document.write(data);
}

showGetResult('test');
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than using `document.write` on what you expect the function to return, the success callback can take care of that for you, like so:

```
success:function(data) {
    document.write(data);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery.ajax({
async: false, //add async false
        url: 'http://localhost/index.php',
        type: 'get',
        dataType: 'text/html',
        success:function(data)
        {
            alert(data);
            result = data;
        } 
     });
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding *why* and/or *how* this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Comment: because if async is true ajax Can not give the value in the required time