# How do I async/await a fetch response?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, fetch-api

I want to use await to save the response to a variable. I need to store that response in a variable and use it in the next code flow. I don't want to store and use variables only inside function braces. In the code below, only one console.log is written, but many events exist. I don't want to use fetch and then. I want to solve it using async/await, but everything I do is wrong. What did I do wrong?

**Try 1**

Run => Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules

```
var resp = await fetch(`https://www.yahoo.com/manifest_desktop_us.json`);  
var jobj = await resp.json();  
var display = jobj.display;  
console.log(display); //I need display value
```

**Try 2**

Run => undefined

```
async function abc(url) {
  var resp = await fetch(url);
  var jobj = await resp.json();
  return jobj;
}
var url = 'https://www.yahoo.com/manifest_desktop_us.json';
var jobj = abc(url);
//var jobj = async() => await abc(url); //undefined
var display = jobj.display;  
console.log(display); //I need display value
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the *whole* logic related to async operation in an `async` function.
You can use an anonymous async function for that:

```js
(async () => {
    var resp = await fetch(`https://www.yahoo.com/manifest_desktop_us.json`);  
    var jobj = await resp.json();  
    var display = jobj.display;  
    console.log(display);
})();
```

Alternatively, since an async function returns a `Promise` you can get the value in a `then` call as well:

```js
async function abc(url) {
  var resp = await fetch(url);
  var jobj = await resp.json();
  return jobj;
}
var url = 'https://www.yahoo.com/manifest_desktop_us.json';
var jobj = abc(url).then((value) => console.log(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

Your 1st try is very much close to get it to work, the error `Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async functions and the top level bodies of modules` means await can only be used within an async function, so you need to wrap it

```
(async function(){
    var resp = await fetch(`https://cors- 
 anywhere.herokuapp.com/https://www.yahoo.com/manifest_desktop_us.json`);  
    var jobj = await resp.json();  
    var display = jobj.display;  
    console.log(display); // logs "standalone" from API
})();
```

In addition, you also need to bypass **cors**, for the sake of demonstration, I've added **cors** URL, but in your production app you must handle it in the global HTTP request instance or have your own backend URL.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `then`.

```
const [data, setData] = useState({})

const getApi = async () => {

const resp = await fetch(`https://www.yahoo.com/manifest_desktop_us.json`)  
return resp

}

getApi().then((resp) => setData(resp.json))
```